# reCaptcha image is not shown with Firefox CanvasBlocker

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

After clicking on the reCatpcha's checkbox, it turned to loading icon but no image was shown. After 5 seconds, the loading icon turned back to checkbox.

I enabled the "Protect window API" in CanvasBlocker which it warned will break reCaptcha and suggested to whitelist it. I added the whitelist but the issue still persist.

Answer (score 0):

As shown by the tooltip, each entry of the list should be **unchecked** to whitelist/exclude it. I somehow accidentally checked it.

reCaptcha works even when Tracking Protection/third-party cookie & tracker blocking is enabled.

[image]